# Reorder columns in csv file

Tags: python, csv

i'm working im a Python script to get some columns of a csv file. The csv file have the next items

```
id,created_time,ad_id,ad_name,adset_id,adset_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,form_id,form_name,travel,full_name,email,phone_number,city
```

and i just want the next columns

```
full_name,campaign_name,form_name,travel,email,phone_number,city
```

The thing is that the columns in the original file not always have the same position, but always have the same name

I have this code with an unknown error

```
import sys
import csv

with open('originalFile.csv', 'r') as infile, open('file2.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    # output dict needs a list for new column ordering
    fieldnames = ["full_name","campaign_name","form_name","travel","email","phone_number","city"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    # reorder the header first
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        if row is not None:
        # writes the reordered rows to the new file
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "orden.py", line 11, in <module>
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 107, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: What exactly is an _unknown error_?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the error is produce when a field is empty

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to ignore extra fields

`writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')`

[More info here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

this was really simple at all, the error goes when there are empty fields. I mean

full_name,campaign_name,form_name,travel,email,phone_number,city
jhon,,,yes,a@gmail.com,0999999,NY

I probe with a previous algorithm to prevent this (in the original .csv file)

```
sed -e 's/,,/,0,/g' originalFile.csv > originalFile2.csv
```